# Are Angular 6 material input dynamic place holders possible?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to dynamically change the placeholder of a Material input's based on calculations happening in the back ground.  These calculations are the results of the user answering other questions on the form.

I have tried playing around with the quotes.  I am relatively new to angular, so I am hopping this is just a formatting error.

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
    <div class="pr-1">
        <mat-form-field class="med">
            <input matInput placeholder="Recommended Value:  {{Info.get('leggoal').value}}" formControlName="leggoalperkg" required>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

I dont get any errors, but the placeholder stays "Recommended Value: " (which is what I would expect when starting to fill out the form)

It should read something like "Recommended Value: 2.5" after enough information has been filled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your html file

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
<div class="pr-1">
    <mat-form-field class="med">
        <input matInput [placeholder]="leggoalperkgPlaceHolder" formControlName="leggoalperkg" required>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Then in your .ts file choose one of them:

```
get leggoalperkgPlaceHolder() {
 return formGroup.get('leggoal').value || 'default placeholder';
}
```

Or you can subscribe to the **formControl.valueChanges** observable

```
// declare variable at class level
leggoalperkgPlaceHolder: string = 'Default placeholder';

// do this, once formGroup or formControl has been initialized.
formControl.valueChanges
.subscribe(val => this.leggoalperkgPlaceHolder = val);
```

Comment: or in the same .html `[placeholder]="formGroup.get('leggoal').value || 'default placeholder'"`

Comment: This worked  the only thing I had to change was

'''
<div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
<div class="pr-1">
    <mat-form-field class="med">
        <input matInput [placeholder]="{{leggoalperkgPlaceHolder}}" formControlName="leggoalperkg" required>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
'''